# bad return type in lambda expression cannot convert Object to T

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I have this lazy iterator that pretty much receives a function and a string as parameters, goes to an API, receives a DTO from the API and converts that DTO to a domain object (in this case an Event). This Event, as seen below is made up of an Artist and several Tracks. My problem (not only here) is that, when in my EventIterator, I try to populate my artistSupplier by passing a lambda expression, I get the error "Bad return type in lambda expression ArtistDto cant be converted to T".

```
public class EventIterator<T, U, R> extends SetListIterator<T, U, R> implements Iterator<R> {

private Function<U, T[]> function;
private String s;
private LastfmApi lastfmApi;

public EventIterator(String s, Function<U, T[]> function, LastfmApi lastfmApi) {
    this.lastfmApi = lastfmApi;
    this.s = s;
    this.function = function;
    page = 1;
}

@Override
public R convertToDomainType(T[] ret) {
    EventDto [] eventDtos = (EventDto[]) ret;
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList<Event>();
    for (EventDto e:
         eventDtos) {
        Event event = new Event(
                e.getArtistName(),
                e.getEventDate(),
                e.getTour(),
                e.getTracksNames(),
                getTracks(e.getTracksNames(), e.getArtistName()),
                e.getSetListId()
         );
        event.setArtistSupplier(
                (b, c) -> new ArtistIterator<R, U, T>(
                        e.getArtistName(),
                        (a) -> lastfmApi.getArtistInfo(e.getArtistName())
                )
        );
        list.add(event);
    }
    return (R) list;
}


public class Event {

private Artist artist;
private Function<String, Artist> artistSupplier;
private String artistName;
private String eventDate;
private String tour;
private String [] tracksNames;
private Iterable<Track> tracks;
private String setlistId;

public void setArtistSupplier(Function<T, U> supplier) {
    this.artistSupplier = supplier;
}

public Artist artist(String s) {
    return artist = (Artist) artistSupplier.apply((T) s);
}

}

public class Artist {

private String name;
private String bio;
private String url;
private String [] imagesUri;
private String mbid;

}

public abstract class SetListIterator<T, U, R> implements Iterator<R> {

protected String s;
protected int page;
protected T []dtos;

@Override
public R next() {
    T[] ret = dtos;
    if (!hasNext())
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    dtos = moveNext();
    return convertToDomainType(ret);
}

public abstract T[] moveNext();

public abstract R convertToDomainType(T[] ret);
}
```

Comment: Thats a lot of code, can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `artistSupplier` function is defined as `Function<String, Artist>` with single `String` input and `Artist` output, while you are trying to pass some function which accepts two arguments `(b,c)` and returns `ArtistIterator`:

```
event.setArtistSupplier(
        (b, c) -> new ArtistIterator<R, U, T>(
                e.getArtistName(),
                (a) -> lastfmApi.getArtistInfo(e.getArtistName())
        )
);
```

Since your code does include `Event#setArtistSupplier` implementation I can just assume, that it is something like this:

```
setArtistSupplier(Function<String,Artist> function) {artistSupplier = function;}
```

**EDIT**

What you need to do is:

```
event.setArtistSupplier((name) -> {
    Artist artist = ...; // convert name to Artist (e. g. load artist based on name)
    return artist;

});
```

Comment: It's exactly like that. But even if I swap the String and Artist with generics it still produces the same error

Comment: even if you change types to generics, the problem remains: you are trying to pass some function with wrong number of arguments. setter requires to pass function with only one input argument, while you are passing function with two input arguments = it is clearly not a `Function` type.

Comment: The thing is I wanted everything to be lazy, so when I asked for an Artist it would then use the Function artistSupplier and populate the Artist

Comment: thats ok, but you need to change your lambda expression to correct from (change arguments declaration part - see my edit).